# Randomly Generating Enemy Stats Depending on Game State

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, random

In my game, I want that, the more the player is playing a game, the harder are the enemies to kill by generating them randomly, like the game "Dungeon Raid" on iOS. Here's the stat that the enemies should have:

- HP
- Attack
- Time: Seconds needed for the enemy before attacking (The higher the time is, the slower is the enemy.)

  - The time varies depending on the attack amount (If the enemy is really strong, it must be slow)
- Score: The score given by the enemy when killed

What I thought could be right to do is to determine the minimum stats that an enemy could get and then increment it depending on the game state and by using an algorithm to calculate them accordingly, but I really don't know how to do it and even where to start.

Comment: You're probably right that this isn't the place for this particular question, but there's a StackExchange site for game development specifically which seems to handle less code-oriented questions.  You can find it here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  [By the way - your English is actually quite good, so don't apologize.]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start by being able to generate random numbers over a specific range. The simplest case is to generate random numbers uniformly between a minimum and a maximum value. As the game progresses you can change the minimum and maximum values to increase along with the stats. of your player.

You could do this like so,

```
NSUInteger BoundedUniformRandomNumber( NSUInteger min, NSUInteger max)
{
    NSUInteger range = max - min;
    u_int32_t randomNumber = (u_int32_t)min + arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)range);
    return (NSUInteger)randomNumber;
}
```

Note that `arc4random_uniform` is from `stdlib` so please include `#import <stdlib.h>`, also the `arc4random_uniform` is half-open, which means that it will return the minimum value, but will never return the maximum value. Therefore the maximum value you will generate in the above function is actually `max - 1`.

Hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: Wow thank you for your great answer! It's sure that I will try to begin with that! I thought of making multiple categories too, like Slow Enemy, Tank, Strong, etc. so I could generate numbers accordingly and add values the more the game is advanced! Well thank you kind sir!

Comment: As you say you're using Cocos2d, Ray Wenderlich's tutorials may also help, especially: http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial